# Querying and format validation of json (analogous to XSD)

Tags: json, validation, xsd

Any good ideas about analogues for XSD (i.e., "schema validation") for JSON?  My search engine skills are failing me.

(FWIW, I'm coming at it from Python.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/)?